# SPARQL in DBpedia return no results

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I try to write a query in SPARQL in DBpedia to return all the info for high schools in a certain country. I run the query on snorql here [link](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/), but it returns "no results". I cannot find any error on my query. Can anyone help?

```
SELECT ?school
WHERE { 
?school a owl:school. 
?school owl:location ?city. 
?city owl:isPartOf ?state. 
?state owl:country <http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States>.
}
```

Edit:

1. http://dbpedia.org/ontology/school
2. http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location
3. http://dbpedia.org/ontology/country

Comment: what is `owl:school`? What is `owl:location`? What is `owl:isPartOf`? What is `owl:country`? These identifiers are not part of [OWL 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-overview/).

Comment: If you visit the link of the Snorql, you will see that there are prefixes that have already set from the virtuoso. For example: `PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be mistaken about the ontologies you should be using. You are using various identifiers from the namespace mapped to the prefix `owl`, namely:

- `owl:school`
- `owl:location`
- `owl:isPartOf`
- `owl:country`

However, as you do not specify a custom prefix mapping, the default mapping is used, according to which `owl` is mapped to `http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#`, which is [OWL 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-overview/). OWL 2 does not contain any definitions for the listed identifiers, and DBpedia accordingly does not use these identifiers.

DBpedia *does* use the identifiers `School`, `location`, `isPartOf` and `country` from the namespace `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/`, which is mapped to the prefix `dbpedia-owl`. Therefore, in your query, just use the prefix for the ontology you actually want to use. Furthermore, note that the *class* [`dbpedia-owl:School`](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/School) is capitalized, [`dbpedia-owl:school`](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/school) with a small *s* is a property.

```sql
SELECT ?school
WHERE { 
    ?school a dbpedia-owl:School. 
    ?school dbpedia-owl:location ?city. 
    ?city dbpedia-owl:isPartOf ?state. 
    ?state dbpedia-owl:country <http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States>.
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I had it as dbpedia-owl before the edit. You can see the history, but I thought it was wrong and change it to owl. Do you know if I can do the same with "Highschool" instead of "School". Replacing it in query doesn't work.

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris: The full list of automatically supported prefixes is linked from the [web-based front-end](http://www.dbpedia.org/sparql), it's [here](http://www.dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl). As for highschools, http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Highschool doesn't show anything, which usually means that such an URI is not defined. There seems to be a http://dbpedia.org/ontology/highschool property, though it's not clear to what extent it is actually applied in the DBpedia data. (Highschool is a very country-specific concept, which is probably why it is not generically defined as a class.)